# Rails - How to generate routes from an Object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, activerecord, routes, helper

Scenario:

- A main Rails Application
- Various Rails Engines, mounted in main Rails Application (routes.rb)

Now Suppose I have an Engine named "Engine" and inside there is a model named "Topic".
Something like `Engine::Topic < ActiveRecord::Base`

Now inside this Engine, if i have to generate route for any instance of `Topic`, i would do something like:

```
@topic = Engine::Topic.first

# inside helpers/views, i can write the below statement

url_for ([@topic]) 

# and it will give me exact "show" route for this topic. Like "/engine/topic/1"
# But this works only inside engines. If i write this inside main Application, 
# it gives an error "undefined method 'topic_path'"
```

Now how can i make this a generalized pattern ?

Means i can have any object of any model (from various Engines) and i would be able to find out its route in a clean way ?

Answer (score 0):

When you mount a rails engine's routes, you can optionally pass `as`.

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount MyEngine::Engine => "/my_engine", as: "my_engine"
  get "/foo" => "foo#index"
end
```

This will provide you with the route helper `my_engine` so that you can use `my_engine.root_url` for example, to access your engine's routes.

*Source: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html .*

EDIT:

Maybe you could do something meta like this? :/

```
@topic.class.parent::Engine.routes.url_for(@topic)
```

Comment: This was not the question. I can create my routes easily and use them. But question was `how to generate routes from any model Object ?`

Comment: Fair enough, sounds like some poor architecture to me, I edited my question with an idea.

Comment: I already tried this one on rails console, and it gives an error "undefined method 'reverse_merge!' for <#Engine::Topic 34d34es4e>"

Comment: If the models in your engine are namespaced (which would be normal AFAIK), for example: `::MyEngine::Topic`, can you try using the suggestion above in your routes file and then do `url_for(my_engine.topic_path(@topic))` in your views - does that work?